# How to Print out the longest streak of heads from a coin toss

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop, printing

I was trying to write a program that that counts the longest streak of heads in a random 100 coin toss, Able to print print out the toss result but I don't how to initialize the count for longest streak and go about it, Am new to programming and python

```
import random
total_heads = 0
count = 0

while count < 100:

    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        print("H")
        total_heads += 1
        count += 1``
    elif coin == 2:
        print("T")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
import random
total_heads = 0
count = 0
longest_streak = 0
current_streak = 0

while count < 100:
    coin = random.randint(1, 2)
    if coin == 1:
        print("H")
        total_heads += 1
        current_streak += 1
        if current_streak > longest_streak:
            longest_streak = current_streak
    else:
        print("T")
        current_streak = 0
    count += 1
print(longest_streak)
print(total_heads)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint as r

heads_streaks = [0]
for i in range(100):
 coin = r(0, 1)
 if not coin:
  print("H")
  heads_streaks[-1] += 1
 else:
  print("T")
  heads_streaks.append(0)
print("longest streak is: {}".format(sorted(heads_streaks, reverse=True)[0]))
```

Comment: I'm getting " 'reversed' is an invalid keyword argument for sort() "  error

Comment: I edited it already, it should say reverse instead of reversed, that was the issue. I tested it and it worked. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of too much magic, these are the tools I'd use:

- [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/random.html#random.choices) can be used to draw your 100 samples in one step
- [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can be used to group these tosses into streaks, i.e. partition the random tosses into groups where the side is the same
- [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) make it very easy to loop over things and pull out the information you want

Putting these together I get:

```
import random
import itertools

# perform 100 coin tosses and print them out
tosses = random.choices('HT', k=100)
print('tosses: ', *tosses)

# turn these into streaks of the same side
streaks = [''.join(streak) for _, streak in itertools.groupby(tosses)]
print('streaks: ', *streaks)

# get the longest streak of heads
lsh = max(len(s) for s in streaks if s[0] == 'H')
print('longest streak of heads: ', lsh)
```

One run of which outputs:

```
tosses: H T H T T T H H T T H H H H T H T T T T H T T H H H H H T T H H H H H H T T T T H T H H T H T T H H H H H H H T T T H T H H T T T H H T T H H T H T H H T H H H T T H T T H T H T H H T T T T T T H T H
streaks: H T H TTT HH TT HHHH T H TTTT H TT HHHHH TT HHHHHH TTTT H T HH T H TT HHHHHHH TTT H T HH TTT HH TT HH T H T HH T HHH TT H TT H T H T HH TTTTTT H T H
longest streak of heads: 7
```